# Facebook friend request not sending

Tags: android, facebook

I am having problems with the Facebook integration in my app. I implemented the connexion and it works like a charm then when I try to send a request to a friend, the notification does not show up in the friend's Facebook app (or website). I have followed this tutorial to implement the request : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests/

I have checked my hash keys and they appear to be correct. I have put the android debug.keystore hash key in the developer settings and in the app hash key. I also disabled the sandbox mode and provided the correct package names and Class name. I have looked everywhere and I cannot seem to find a solution.

If someone has a clue of what my problem is it would be great :).

Here is my code :

```
private void sendRequestDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message",
            "Learn how to make your Android apps social");

    final Session session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(mContext);

    WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(
            mContext, session, params)).setOnCompleteListener(
            new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.id.request_cancelled,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.id.network_error,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        final String requestId = values
                                .getString("request");
                        if (requestId != null) {
                                sendRequest(friend_facebook_id, session);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.id.request_cancelled,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }).build();
    requestsDialog.show();



}

protected void sendRequest(String friend_facebook_id, Session session) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message",
            "Learn how to make your Android apps social");
    params.putString("to", friend_facebook_id);

    WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(
            mContext, session, params)).setOnCompleteListener(
            new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Request cancelled",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Network Error",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        final String requestId = values
                                .getString("request");
                        if (requestId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Request sent",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Request cancelled",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }).build();
    requestsDialog.show();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your source for sending the request?

Comment: I just edited my first post. Thanks for your help :)